# When I connect my phone to my laptop using USB connection, I can't get either of them to recognize the other?

Tags: usb, connection-issues, file-transfer

I've tried turning on usb debugging and updating usb drivers from device manager and nothing happened. I've also tried connecting the phone to an Acer Chromebook 15 that I own and still can't get the phone or the laptop to recognize other. Only the charging worked in both cases.

There isn't any notification in the notification areas.

The phone in question is the Pixel 4a with Android 13 and the laptop is the Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ALC6 with Windows 11.

Comment: You might want to try different USB cables: [Google Pixel 4 doesn't work with some USB cables (Update: Google responds)](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-pixel-4-usb-c-cables-1056579/)

Comment: I've tried connecting it with the cable that comes in the box and the only thing that happens is that the phone starts to charge.

Comment: For Windows, you possibly need to install [Google USB driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb). However, [Chrome OS shouldn't require additional configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device), so the cable might really be the culprit, even if it's the one from the box.

Comment: I've tried with a Samsung Galaxy A12 from a friend and the Samsung recognized it as soon as I plugged it in and show me popup about data and file transfer access on both the Acer and the Lenovo.